# Защита от удаления

Tags: php

У меня на сайте, есть ссылка с GET параметрами `?interface-admin=1&del-id=1` если на неё нажать, то админ удалится.

Так вот, я это всё поместил в img

```
<img src="http://localhost/dashboard/sait/?interface-admin=1&del-id=1">
```

и если это изображение загрузить, то админ удалится.

Как тут быть, что бы не подделывали запрос? Хранить всё в текстовых файлах?

Comment: блок кода, который принимает запрос на удаление, пропишите в условии if () , в котором проверяйте, является ли текущий пользователь админом, или нет.

Comment: Позволяйте это действие авторизованному пользователю со специальным логином и паролем.А так вопрос слишком общий.Разбивайте его на части и по кусочкам приводя больше кода, получайте конкретные ответы

Comment: @Эдуард может имеется в виду XSS

Comment: Расскажите лучше, какую задачу вы хотите таким образом решить? Это какая-то резервная мера безопасности? Может быть, есть вариант проще. Кстати, по этому запросу наверняка можно поудалять всех пользователей, перебирая `id`.

Comment: @DivMan, csrf токен в такие ссылки нужно добавить и проверять его соответствие на стороне сервера https://www.google.ru/search?q=csrf+%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B5%D0%BD

Answer (score 7):

Классика [CSRF](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D0%B6%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B0) уязвимости.

Во-первых: ничего не удаляйте и не изменяйте по GET-запросу. GET-запросы должны только читать, по стандарту полагается, что они не изменяют состояние системы, потому безопасны и могут выполняться многократно. Иногда даже без ведома пользователя, например, для фоновой подгрузки следующей страницы. Для изменения состояния используйте POST-запросы.

Исключением является только та ситуация, когда вам действительно нужен GET-запрос. Например, для ссылки "отписаться" в рассылке или других, где вы понимаете, что и зачем делаете.

Во-вторых: так же не составляет труда попросить выполнить браузер при заходе на специально-оформленную страницу простой POST-запрос без ведома пользователя (в частности, как результат XSS атаки). Изменяющие данные запросы должны быть защищены токеном безопасности, который должен передаваться вместе с запросом.

Comment: `используйте POST-запросы` – а почему не `DELETE`?

Comment: @NickVolynkin , хороший вопрос. Меня очень смущает, что в формах я встречал только GET и  POST запросы - допускаю, что существуют проблемы с кроссбраузерностью, которых явно нет с POST'ом. А в REST-api и PATCH, PUT, DELETE распространены. Нужен комментарий опытного фронтендщика.

Comment: @NickVolynkin [в стандарте HTML 5.1 разрешены только GET и POST](https://www.w3.org/TR/html51/sec-forms.html#element-attrdef-form-method)

Comment: @andreymal хм, интересно. А вы не встречали какого-нибудь документа, объясняющего такое архитектурное решение? Наверняка оно было обдуманным.

Comment: @NickVolynkin хз, самому интересно)

Comment: @andreymal задал вопрос: [Почему в HTML 5.1 разрешены только GET и POST?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/675420/181472)

Answer (score 0):

Не совсем понял зачем тег `<img>`, но лучше использовать метод POST как говорилось выше. У меня например при клике на кнопку вызывается модальное окно в котором спрашивается действительно ли я хочу совершить данное действие, будь то удаление или редактирование (так сказать защита от случайного действия), при нажатии на кнопку "Да" отправляется AJAX запрос с данными (например ID) методом POST после чего обрабатывается и выполняется действие, и то при условии что уровень доступа администратор, а при нажатии кнопки "Отмена", модальное окно закрывается.

Comment: Не защитит от поддельной формы, отправляющей POST-запрос с удалением на ваш сайт (см. соседний ответ)

Comment: @andreymal, Внимательно читайте я не сказал про подделку POST, речь шла об случайном удалении!!! И написал что нужно делать проверку (**и то при условии что уровень доступа администратор**), нужно делать банальную проверку на авторизацию, тогда никакой подделки не будет!

Comment: CSRF успешно обходит любую проверку авторизации. Алсо, вопрос не про случайное удаление, а именно про подделку :) Ваш вариант от подделки не защищает (ещё раз см. соседний ответ)

Comment: @andreymal, Ок! Что мешает добавить token, а потом его проверить?

Comment: Ничего не мешает, но в вашем ответе про это ничего)

Comment: @andreymal, Так, а в вопросе об CSRF тоже ни слова... И вообще я не это имел ввиду... Я думал о банальном поменять id1 на id2, и вставить в адресную строку)))