# Почему в формах в HTML 5.1 разрешены только GET и POST?

Tags: html5, http

Протокол HTTP 1.1 [включает в себя 9 методов](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html): GET, POST, PUT, DELETE и прочие.

При этом HTML 5.1 [предполагает использование *в формах* только двух из них](https://www.w3.org/TR/html51/sec-forms.html#element-attrdef-form-method): GET и POST:

> The `method` and `formmethod` content attributes are [enumerated attributes](https://www.w3.org/TR/html51/infrastructure.html#enumerated-attributes) with the following keywords and states:
>
> - The keyword `get`, mapping to the state **GET**, indicating the HTTP GET method.
> - The keyword `post`, mapping to the state **POST**, indicating the HTTP POST method.

Почему не поддерживаются или не используются остальные? На чем основано такое архитектурное решение?

В частности, если логика моего приложения подразумевает *идемпотентное* удаление элемента, как и зачем я должен выбирать между по определению *неидемпотентным* POST и не подходящим по смыслу GET?

Навеяно обсуждением [ответа про XSRF-уязвимости](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/675304/181472).

Comment: Одна маленькая поправка - html предполагает `GET` и `POST` **для форм**. А то звучит так, как будто остальные методы c HTML использовать нельзя

Comment: @Darth спасибо, уточнил.

Comment: Сугубо логическая мысль - потому-что форма по определению предпологает передачу данных от клиента к серверу. Но это сугубо домслы.

Comment: GET для форм запроса, POST Для форм создания объектов. Редактирование и удаление и пр - в виде отдельных не "форменных" запросов - видимо чтобы приучить создание "живого" интерфейса редактирование данных.

Comment: Я очень сомневаюсь, что кто-то, кроме авторов драфта сможет ответить на вопрос "На чем основано такое архитектурное решение?".

Comment: @VenZell я не расстроюсь, если вы проголосуете за закрытие. Это тоже ответ. :)

Comment: А по какому критерию кто-то должен голосовать за закрытие? Это не дубликат; вопрос чётко описан и гарантированно воспроизводим; написан на русском языке; не подразумевает дискуссии (т. е. не содержит посыла вида *а как вы думаете, ..?*).

Comment: @Arhad, по идее "Вопрос порождает бесконечные прения и дискуссии, основанные не на знаниях, а на мнениях.". А почему так, я уже ответил - ответить на вопрос могут только авторы драфта и больше никто. Остальные могут строить догадки.

Comment: @VenZell авторы драфта могут объяснять свои решения, информация о спецификации может быть доступна вне нее. w3c именно так и работает: пишется драфт, ведется обсуждение (и оно может быть вообще везде), пилится реализация, переписывается драфт... потому здесь не обязательно будет чье-то мнение, кто-нибудь может знать официальную позицию автора драфта.

Comment: @SashaOmelchenko, я долго искал информацию, нашел только RFC 2616 в котором описаны доступные методы. Из их описания я так и не смог определить, почему они не используется в w3c. В нем тоже нет пояснений.

Comment: Не соглашусь с закрытием по указанной причине, всё-таки это свершившийся факт, у которого определённо есть какая-то конкретная причина (пусть даже вида «ну нам в w3c так захотелось»), которая может служить объективным ответом в контексте SO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Тот самый вопрос](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/114156/why-are-there-are-no-put-and-delete-methods-on-html-forms).

Если коротко, когда-то [даже предлагалось](https://www.w3.org/Bugs/Public/show_bug.cgi?id=10671) поддержать эти методы в формах, для того, чтобы браузеры без поддержки скриптового движка могли выполнять такие запросы, высказывались и другие точки зрения "за", по ссылке полное обсуждение. А Mozilla даже [добавила их поддержку](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-html-comments/2011Mar/0007.html) в beta-версии своего браузера, но дальше дело не пошло.

Ну а вот, хоть и скупой, но от принимавших стандарт [ответ](https://www.w3.org/Bugs/Public/show_bug.cgi?id=10671#c16) на ваш вопрос. Тогда и был изменен статус на "WONTFIX". Собственно, всё дело в семантике.

> PUT as a form method makes no sense, you wouldn't want to PUT a form payload. DELETE only makes sense if there is no payload, so it doesn't make much sense with forms either.